# Getting Data from the existing data #c.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have used this code to display the employee's first name and last name from the provided database when an employee id number is typed into the text box and the “Find” button is clicked. But I will also need Previous and Next Button to display previous and next records respectively in textbox as well. Is there a  method like MovePrevious and MoveNext sth to get it?

Here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\CCEMPLOYEE.mdb";
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    {
       using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_mi FROM Employee WHERE emp_id =@ID "))
        {
           if (idText.Text != "")
           {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(idText.Text));
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              cmd.Connection = con;
              con.Open();
              using (OleDbDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                 try
                 {
                    sdr.Read();
                    fnameText.Text = sdr["emp_fname"].ToString();
                    lnameText.Text = sdr["emp_lname"].ToString();
                    miText.Text = sdr["emp_mi"].ToString();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                 }
              }
           }
           else
           {
              MessageBox.Show("You did not enter any ID", "Enter the ID ",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK);
           }
           con.Close();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is previous? What is next? based on what?

Comment: This is a code I used to display the names of employee when relevant ID is typed in the textbox. Now I need the previous and next button so that it will show the previous and next record of the typed ID in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to go Next or Previous in your provided code because you only have one record in your recordset.

You will also have the problem that you haven't specified the basis for what "Previous" and "Next" mean, the framework has no idea that you mean next by emp_id (or do you mean next by alphabetical surname?)

I would suggest your Prev and Next buttons need to be aware of what "this" record is, and use that as a parameter to run a similar piece of code when they are clicked. You could add an int property to your class, have the Find button store the emp_id into that property, and then have the Next and Prev buttons call almost identical code except with the SQL adjusted to something like "SELECT TOP 1 emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_mi FROM Employee WHERE emp_id > @ID ORDER BY emp_id ASC" (note I don't have anything on me to test this at the moment, you might need to sort DESC).

The reason I've suggested TOP 1, > and ORDER By is I don't know if you have a guarantee that you have sequential emp_id - obviously if you know they're sequential and can guarantee that always you could just go "SELECT... WHERE emp_id = @ID-1" for Prev...

This answer is academic, not practical, I don't suggest this is a good solution to a production scenario - it's an answer to your question.

Comment: emp_id is the name of the column. 
I think ID-1 won't work as the Ids are random and not sequential. 
Maybe the index of rows and columns is needed.  I added some codes but the record starts from the beginning and not from the typed IDs.

Comment: if your database is SQL you could look at using ROWNUMBER if you've got a recordset, but again that's not a production solution especially if the database is large.

If you're actually building something for a purpose, I'd suggest you should probably be looking at a paging technique however I can't see why you'd also want to be able to page after zooming to a specific record by a random id, so it's hard to really recommend a solution.

Comment: Actually, > @ID  seems to work for the next button. 
What about previous one?

I will need a loop because it only shows one next record after the typed one. Can we do that?

My idTextBox.Text remains the same. It does not change when the record is different. How can I solve that? I don't think I need try catch in previous next button.

Comment: If > @ ID worked for next, < @ ID should work for previous (change the sort between ASC and DESC accordingly).

Make sure you handle no result - when you have the minimum or maximum record already and the query brings back zero rows.

Comment: It did not! 

And it won't go through loops too